# Filter XML Data in DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, filter

I have a simple project that I am experimenting for learning JavaScript. I was able to call data to the html document using JavaScript. Next I would like to filter through that list with like a search feature. However I receive an error on line 38 of JavaScript file.

```
if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
```

I don't understand why type is undefined. I did find out that it means it has not been assigned a value. Please correct me if I misunderstood what I read. Not sure where to look next. Any help will be appreciated. I am not a guru just a noob who wants to learn.

HTML

```
<!html doctype>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h2>XMLHttpRequest</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search 
for names.."/>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function init(){

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (this.readyState ==4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseXML);
            var schools = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("school");
            var strOut = "<ul id='myUL'>";
            for(i=0; i<schools.length; i++){
                var name = schools[i].getElementsByTagName("name") 
[0].innerHTML;
                var web = schools[i].getElementsByTagName("web") 
[0].innerHTML;
                strOut += "<li><ahref='"+web;
                strOut += "' target='_blank'>" + name + "</a></li>";
        }
        strOut += "</ul>";
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = strOut;
    }

};

xhttp.open('get', 'myXML.xml', true);
xhttp.send();
}
window.onload = init;

//Filter List
function myFunction() {
// Declare variables
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

// Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search 
query
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sites>
    <school>
        <name>Middle Georgia State University</name>
        <web>http://www.mga.edu</web>
    </school>
    <school>
        <name>Columbus State University</name>
        <web>http://www.columbusstate.edu</web>
    </school>
    <school>
        <name>University of Georgia</name>
        <web>http://www.uga.edu</web>
    </school>
</sites>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two typos:
1. `strOut += "<li><ahref='"+web;` should be `strOut += "<li><a href='"+web;`
2. `a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("li")[0];` should be`a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];`

Comment: @wink, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

As you have already extracted an array of li tags in below line of your code:

```
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

So there is no need to use "getElementsByTagName" function again inside for loop, instead you can just access li elements just by using array index as below :

```
a = li[i];
```

Also instead of using innerHTML function in if condition use innerText function, because innerHTML will return full anchor tag that is inside li element but innerText will only return school name from li element.

After doing this your for loop will look like below :

```
// Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i];
    if (a.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't even notice that at first. I appreciate you showing me how to improve my code.